# Remove Permissions Panel

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users, permission-levels

How to remove permissions panel option from view?

I'd like to be able to setup where when an external user logs in and on the documents page, they cannot see which members are part of the group, nor is able to manage access.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB method to remove permission panel option from the view.

As a workaround, I recommend you not give Full Control permission level to the external users. In that way, the external users cannot manage access.

If it’s not feasible for your requirement, you can use code to customize the details pane by SPFx extension.

Reference: [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss) or [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

Comment: thank you, how exactly do I go about removing full control permission level to the external users?

Comment: Use site owner account to go to site settings->site permissions->select the relevant external user account->click Edit user permission.

Comment: Thanks, actually I already have that corrected, they have read permissions, and the limited access permission is checked as well but greyed out, thats odd they can still see the permission panel option from the view, perhaps a new view needs to be created? Think it is possible to create views for certain groups? I've got about 50 external users from at least 5 different domains, and each external user is in a different group